# Real Time personalized videos

Tags: video, webvideos

I would like to achieve a video with custom text pulled from a database or user input as the following : 
http://videopersonalization.net/kia.html

Can somebody shed some light on the process without using a third party please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is effectively a streaming media server tied to a live renderer.  Rather than save a recorded video, when you make a request for the video, it accesses a live stream.  That live stream uses the contents of the request to run a template video and encode in real time.  That real time stream is then played for the user.

You could probably manage to wire something like Red5 up to be able to do this with some alterations.  The big trick would be kicking off the live stream as part of the processes.  You also need sufficient rendering hardware to be able to generate a distinct live stream for each request.  You also need a real time video rendering system that can work with templates.  There is tech like this for video mixers, but I'm not sure of any particular software that does it in software in real time.  Some streaming oriented software may be able to do it though.

Comment: How does Facebook do it ?

Comment: @AliGajani - not sure what you mean?  While I was an early facebook user, I haven't used it much on the main site since the introduction of apps, so you'll have to clarify a bit more.

Comment: Couldn't this also be done with Flash? Pre-render a video with transparency, then put it on top of a dynamically generated background?

Comment: @Corey - sure, you would be better off at that point to play the video flat as the back plate and use Flash to place the text though.  But in this day and age Flash video is EXTREMELY limiting.  Most mobile devices don't support it and an increasing number of desktops have it blocked or not installed from security concerns.  The quality also probably wouldn't be quite as good without quite a lot of careful development of the Flash animation.